# Html video as full screen background without controls in iPhone

Tags: html

I am building hybrid mobile app using ionic and I need to display video as a full screen background. I tried lot of sample code provided on stack overflow and other resources but nothing seems to work on iPhone. It's strange that following the general comments from people, I can get it working on iPad and all android devices but iPhone.

Comment: i think background video not support in  all ios  touch device if i not wrong

Comment: Did you try Vide.js ? http://vodkabears.github.io/vide/

Comment: Did you add `<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true"/>` to config.xml ?

Comment: Thanks guys.. I'll give it a go....

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your help, I can get the video working but same issue with controls. Controls are still visible. Do you have any working example to share? or is there any git repo I can clone?